# Wordpress visitor ip address

Tags: wordpress, security

Is there any way I can get a user's ip address who search for "something" in the past on a wordpress site. I haven't install any plugins for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Add get_visitor_ip function to your theme's functions.php or in the theme's child. You need to enable HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in your web server logging as well. It is possible that the captured IP address string has more than one IP separated by a comma due to two HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR layers of proxies (so rare, but it would be great if someone could explain to me how this happens!). For this reason, I use a PRCE match to take the first matched IP address.

```
 function get_visitor_ip() {
    if (!empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        //to check ip from share internet
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        //to check ip is from proxy
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    // match first IP address for possibility that the captured IP address string 
    // has more than one IP due to two HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR layers of proxies
    $re = '/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/s';
    $matches = array();
    if(preg_match($re, $ip, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0) === 1) {
        $ip = $matches[0][0];
    }
    return apply_filters('wpb_get_ip', $ip);
 }
 add_shortcode('visitor_ip', 'get_visitor_ip');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the plugin [wp-statistics](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-statistics/)  which will track users. This plugin will help you to Track statistics for your WordPress site  .

Answer (score -1):

You can install this plugin for wordpress to see from what websites users got referred to your website: https://wordpress.org/plugins/statpress-visitors/
It also has this feature: "New page "URL Monitoring" which shows all URLs requested that do not correspond to the posts and pages written by an author in order to deny access to intruders or hackers." 
And it shows IPs with geo location.

Comment: I want to get a user's ip addres who is already visit the. This doesn't help me.

Comment: Unless the server, a script you wrote or an application you installed recorded the IP for you, I don't think that is doable.